# PHP: Using bcrypt for password encryption

Tags: php, password-encryption

I am still new to PHP. I tried Mr. Andrew Moore's method. The password wasn't matching. I tried playing with [Andrew Liu's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481199/php-mysql-using-bcrypt-hash-and-verifying-password-with-database/12932732#12932732)
and the answers from the post. When I try to var_dump I am not getting true or false. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please let me know?

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15); 
$username = sanitize($username);
$password = $_POST['password'];

DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'users');

$dbh = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$check_username = $dbh->prepare("SELECT password FROM user WHERE username= '$username'");
$check_username -> execute(array($username));

while($row = $check_username->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $check_password = $row['password'];
    $isGood = $bcrypt->verify($password, $check_password);
    var_dump($isGood);
}
```

Comment: what **are** you getting from `var_dump` then?

Comment: I modified the code a bit later. I am getting false for var_dump now. I am entering my password as plaintext and I have the hashed version for "check_password" retrieved from the database. I can't seem to get the $isGood = $bcrypt->verify($password, $check_password); working. I am using XAMPP with PHP Version 5.3.8.

Comment: Are you sure your getting the correct record? `var_dump($row)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Can you compare hashed password with what is stored in db?
I had similar problem and then I realized hash in db is truncated.
Changing password column size from Varchar(40) to Varchar(125) solved my problem.