# php to MySQL using PDO with bcrypt

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bcrypt

I have been using PHP 5.0 with MySQL 4.x with MD5 security. Due to circumstance, i have to use PHP 5.3 with bcrypt and PDO for MySQL.

Attached is the sample code that i used from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481199/php-mysql-using-bcrypt-hash-and-verifying-password-with-database) and adopted. It that does not contain any syntax errors during runtime but it doesn't work. The var_dump in the 'while' statement doesn't give out any output.

```
$email = strtolower($_POST['email']);
$pw = $_POST['pw'];

$chk_email= $dbh->prepare("SELECT pw FROM users WHERE email = $email");
$chk_email -> execute(array($email));

while($row = $chk_email->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $chk_pass = $row['pw']; 
    $pass_isGood = $bcrypt->verify($_POST['pw'], $chk_pass);
    var_dump($pass_isGood); 

}
```

Since i'm totally new in bcrypt and PDO, i'm sure its just syntax issue. Any pointers is much appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but by saying "MD5 securit" you indicate you got no idea what "MD5" is and what "security" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$chk_email= $dbh->prepare("SELECT pw FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$chk_email -> execute(array($email));
$row = $chk_email->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$pass_isGood = $bcrypt->verify($_POST['pw'], $row['pw']);
if(!$pass_isGood){
    echo "Incorrect password";
}else{
    echo "Good password";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your prepare statement to:

```
$chk_email = $dbh->prepare("SELECT pw FROM users WHERE email = ?");
```

Comment: still not getting anything...